# Node.js Unexplained memory growth (leak?) from simple program

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, v8

I thought that I understood how node / v8 memory management works but evidently not.

The following program exhibits an rss that grows more or less constantly while the heapUsed grows and then shrinks when the garbage collector runs.

A recent test had the RSS start at ~10 MB and grow to ~14MB over the course of 7 minutes.  Then it continues to grow, hour after hour.

*I've tried setting all the vars within report() to null and I've tried deleting them but neither of these has any effect.*

*I've tried manually invoking the garbage collector.  That slows the growth but does not eliminate it.*

Could someone explain why this is?  Is this normal behavior and I'm just not waiting long enough for the gc to work on the RSS?  This is just one simple example of software I've written that exhibits similar behavior.

```
var startTime = new Date();

var memInfo = {
    rss: 0,
    heapTotal: 0,
    heapUsed: 0
}

function report () {
    var endTime, timeDiff, seconds, minutes, hours, days, mem;

    endTime = new Date();
    timeDiff = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
    seconds = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
    minutes = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 60);
    hours = Math.round(timeDiff % 24);
    timeDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / 24);
    days = timeDiff;

    console.log('Up for %d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds', days, hours, minutes, seconds);

    var mem = process.memoryUsage();
    if (mem.rss > memInfo.rss) { memInfo.rss = mem.rss; }
    if (mem.heapTotal > memInfo.heapTotal) { memInfo.heapTotal = mem.heapTotal; }
    if (mem.heapUsed > memInfo.heapUsed) { memInfo.heapUsed = mem.heapUsed; }

    console.log('Latest', process.memoryUsage());
    console.log('Max   ', memInfo);
};

var timer = setInterval(report, 1000);
```

An even simpler example that does the same thing is:

```
var memInfo = {
    rss: 0,
    heapTotal: 0,
    heapUsed: 0
}

var timer = setInterval(function () {
    var mem = process.memoryUsage();
    if (mem.rss > memInfo.rss) { memInfo.rss = mem.rss; }
    if (mem.heapTotal > memInfo.heapTotal) { memInfo.heapTotal = mem.heapTotal; }
    if (mem.heapUsed > memInfo.heapUsed) { memInfo.heapUsed = mem.heapUsed; }

    console.log('Latest', process.memoryUsage());
    console.log('Max   ', memInfo);

}, 1000);
```

Comment: What OS are node version are you running? On Xubuntu 14.04 with Node v0.10.32, my RSS size increased for a while and then stabilized at around 33MB. Been running for about 8 hours now.

Comment: I'm using 0.10.29.  Your confirmation of the symptom in a later version is a good datapoint.  It would sure be useful if someone with node expertise would put together a best-practices document for node.  There are a few blog articles about but they are mostly targeted at people putting web servers together.  Almost everything I use node for is to create real-time data transfer clients and servers.

Comment: To me, that behavior doesn't seem that bad, since it stabilized.

Comment: Many of the node programs I run don't 'stablize' until they've consumed 135 megs of memory, from a starting point of 17MB.  There are at any given time 26 - 30 of these tasks running, serving various ports and doing other things.    This means somewhere around 3 + GB of memory used in this mysterious way.  I guess as much as anything I'd like to understand what is consuming the memory to aid in updating the tasks for optimal memory consumption.